# In react-native, how to correctly order data-fetching and useState that depends on the data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, apollo-client

I am new to react-native so apologies if this is a dumb question.

I have the following code (only showing the relevant part):

```
const Alarms = () => {

  var { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ALARMS_QUERY) // this line fetches data with Apollo Client
  if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;

  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");
  const [displayed, setDisplayed] = React.useState(data.alarms.items)

  ...
}
```

query and setQuery are used to manage the state of the query that user types into a search bar.
displayed and setDisplayed are used to manage the state of the filtered items that will appear as a FlatList down below the search bar.

This gives an error:

> Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

And I understand that it's because I put state management after two if-statements. However, how to go around this? I can't put state management before if-statements since it depends on the existence of data.

Could someone kindly help me? Thank you!

Comment: I dont understand why dont you put states before the returns? What do they depend on?

Comment: @İlker [displayed, setDisplayed] depends on data. I want to set the initial state to data.alarms.items, which is only possible if data has been fetched (in the useQuery line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Alarms = () => {

  var { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ALARMS_QUERY) // this line fetches data with Apollo Client
 const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");
 const [displayed, setDisplayed] = React.useState("")

  useEffect(()=> {
if(data){
  setDisplayed(data.alarms.items)
}

                 }, [data])


  if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;

 

  ...
}
```

You can set the displayed state an empty string first, if data is coming asynchronously, you can set it with useEffect later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried this but it gives me an exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.alarms'). I also had this error when I simply moved state management before the if statements. I think it's because when it's loading, data is null. Is there any other way around this? Thanks again

Comment: sorry, that's because useEffect works when it renders first. We need to put an if check, I'm updating the answer